# I'm getting an empty dataframe trying to web scrape html code. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, scrape

Trying to use Python 3.x and pandas to scrape salary data from Basketball-Reference. I'm not getting any error messages, but I have no output. I want the second and fourth columns from the table: 'Player' and salary '2019-20'. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I have so far:

```
# URL page we will scraping
salaries_url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/contracts/players.html'
salaries_response = requests.get(salaries_url)
page = salaries_response.text

# this is the HTML from the given URL
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

#This takes the player salaries data, and creates a list of a lists, where a list is all the values of a player
salaries = []
for x in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds_salaries = x.find_all('td')
    name_s = tds_salaries[0].text
    salary = tds_salaries[2].text
    salaries.append([name_s, salary[1:]])

#create a salary pandas dataframe
salaries_df = pd.DataFrame(salaries, columns=['name', 'salary'])

salaries_df.head()
```

Comment: Does that website use javascript to dynamically create the page content?  The `requests` library doesn't do javascript.

Comment: @John Gordon I don't believe so. I was able to successfully scrape the player statistics from the site; I'm just having issues with the salary table.

Comment: As a debugging step, print `salaries` after the loop.  That will at least tell you if it's a page scraping issue, or a dataframe conversion issue.

Comment: If you view source you can see it's static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked fine here. All I did was putting a try inside the for loop to skip the table headers.

### Code

```
salaries_url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/contracts/players.html'
salaries_response = requests.get(salaries_url)
page = salaries_response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

salaries = []
for x in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    try:
        tds_salaries = x.find_all('td')
        name_s = tds_salaries[0].text
        salary = tds_salaries[2].text
        salaries.append([name_s, salary[1:]])
    except IndexError:
        print('This is a header!')

salaries_df = pd.DataFrame(salaries, columns=['name', 'salary'])

print(salaries_df)
```

### Outuput

```
                  name      salary
0        Stephen Curry  40,231,758
1    Russell Westbrook  38,506,482
2           Chris Paul  38,506,482
3            John Wall  38,199,000
4         James Harden  38,199,000
..                 ...         ...
570    Hollis Thompson      50,000
571         Tyler Ulis      50,000
572  Demetrius Jackson      18,312
573    Jordan Caroline       6,000
574    Anthony Bennett       6,000

[575 rows x 2 columns]
```